# Can I access the document or window objects from within a protractor test?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

Maybe this isn't possible, I don't really understand how node works yet. I'd like to be able to run an assertion on the document object after a page has been fetched in protractor. Is such a thing possible, and if so how?

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, so am answering my own question for others:

You can execute javascript using browser.executeScript and then use the return value in your promise resolution, like so:

```js
browser.executeScript('return document._config').then( function(_config){
        expect( _config.epid ).toBe( 1 );
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

The feature you are looking for is called executeScript or executeAsyncScript. They will help you execute an arbitrary piece of javascript in the browser.

Take a look at these links:
http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript
http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript